# Maximum value of a mapping on a compact subset of $\ell^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $A = \{x \in \ell^{2}: \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n|x_{n}|^{2} \leq 1\}$. What is the largest value $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x_{n}e^{in\theta}\right|\, d\theta$ can take on $A$?

Answer (score 2):

Define $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$ as:
$$f(\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x_n e^{ni\theta}.$$
Then $f$ is a $L_2$-function with zero mean over $(0,2\pi)$, and we have:
$$\|f\|_1 \leq \sqrt{2\pi}\,\|f\|_2 \tag{1}$$
due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and 
$$\|f\|_2 \leq \|f'\|_2\tag{2}$$
due to [Wirtinger's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions), or just Parseval's identity. $(1)$ and $(2)$ give:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x_n e^{ni\theta}\right|\,d\theta\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.\tag{3}$$
Probably this can be improved a little, since equality cannot hold both in $(1)$ and in $(2)$.

Comment: But now that we're working with an $L^{2}$ function, I'm not sure if Wirtinger's inequality still applies.